# Wt httpd for production server

Tags: c++, wt

It appears that there are two popular ways to run a Wt application: FastCGI with a server like Apache or their built in httpd. I am familiar with the former but not the latter.

Does anyone have any experience running a Wt app with httpd *in production*? Is this a good idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I eneded up going to Wt forums and asking the creators of the library the same question. Here is what they had to say:

> "The built-in httpd has some benefits wrt we sockets support and use of a sync I/O. We recommend it for most deployments, usually in combination with a reverse proxy such as HAproxy."

Comment: Would you have a link to his answer on the forum?